# App crashing due to OutOfMemoryException from drawables

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-drawable

When I clicked the "level" `Button` (`btnlvlform`) on my `NormalMode` class, it says `UNFORTUNATELY, (MY GAME) has stopped` and I can't figure out why. I can't see the error. I already checked `LevelForm` Class and  `NormalMode` as well as their corresponding XML. Please help me.

**NORMALMODE class:**

```
public class NormalMode extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal_mode);

    }

    public void action(View v){
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id==R.id.btnlvlform){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,LvlForm1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (id==R.id.btnback2){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,StartForm.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
  }
}
```

When I clicked `btnlvlform`, it will go here.

**LvlForm1.java (LEVEL FORM)**

```
public class LvlForm1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lvl_form1);
}

public void action(View v){
int id = v.getId();
if (id==R.id.btnluneta1){
Intent intent= new Intent(this,NewGame1.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnvigan1){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,NewGame2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnleyte1){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,NewGame3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnpaoay1){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,NewGame4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnbataan1){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,NewGame5.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnback5){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,NormalMode.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lvl_form1, menu);
    return true;

   }

}
```

**This is the XML for NormalMode.java**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundtemporary"
tools:context=".NormalMode" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnlvlform"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
    android:background="@drawable/levelform" 
    android:onClick="action"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnback2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back2" 
    android:onClick="action"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
01-20 21:16:42.532: E/dalvikvm-heap(1102): Out of memory on a 14785968-byte allocation.
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.luksongbakagame/com.example.luksongbakagame.LvlForm1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.example.luksongbakagame.LvlForm1.onCreate(LvlForm1.java:14)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     ... 11 more
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     ... 24 more
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:583)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
01-20 21:16:42.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     ... 27 more
```

Comment: Can you please attach the message in LogCat when this happens? Will make it much easier for us to help you

Comment: It could be ActivityNotFoundException. See if you had added the activity LvlForm1 to AndriodManifest.xml

Comment: How can I attach the message in Logcat?

Comment: Just copy it/ save it to a file and add it to your post as an edit.

Comment: I have a LvlForm1 Activity in my manifest.

Comment: Logcat is empty but I have an error log. Should I post it instead with it's details?

Comment: As long as it is the errors from your stacktrace, yes post that

Comment: i posted the error for logcat. i copied it all

Comment: What size are the bitmaps?

Comment: I have a problem again with same issue. "Unfortunately, (My Game) has stopped" in another activities.

Comment: So, what size are the bitmaps?

Comment: 130dp is the size of the bitmap

Comment: My game is crashing again. Same problem. Same forms. I did the answer already then it works. But after a while, it is crashing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your background drawables (background image) is far to big, therefore your app runs out of memory

Check your images and scale them.
`@drawable/backgroundtemporary` `@drawable/levelform` `@drawable/back2`

You should provide different images with different size for different screen densities.

Comment: Thank you! This solution works. I just changed the size of the image in my xml.

Comment: But sadly, it crashed again. I changed the size again but nothing works.

Comment: My game is crashing again. Same problem. Same forms. I did the answer already then it works. But after a while, it is crashing again.

Comment: still out of memory while inflating? how many kilobytes are your background images

Comment: It's 1.50 Mb. Should I resize it?

Comment: of course you should! mostbandroid apps (drpending on device) has only  16 mb ram (low devices) up to 40 mb for high end devices ... check all your drawables, they should not be more than 500 kb, reduce width, height (according screensize), increase compression, reduce quality

Comment: It crashed again. But with another form involved and different problem in logcat.

Comment: alright, and what do expect from me ^^ I can't read your logcat or syacktrace ... But if it's not a out of memory exception then you may consider ask as new question

Comment: Ok. I'll ask another question :)